# C++ program to get the current time

Tags: c++, time

I have to create a simple window service program which is to be executed in visual studio using C++ language. I have used `ctime` and `localtime` keywords but it returns an error saying:

> This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using any other ....

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of the relevant code itself instead of just describing it?

Comment: You can basically put the error message verbatim into your favorite search engine, and get plenty of results providing solutions or at least hints about solutions.

Comment: @Jaya madhu you can also google to get your program

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking, `ctime` and `localtime` are not keywords but identifiers. ([List of C++ keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)). Things with identifiers may be eclipsed but keywords may not (or should not). That's a difference.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` function to get the current time point.

Answer (score 3):

`ctime` and `localtime` are unsafe as these returns pointer to static data.

Therefore, `ctime_s` and `localtime_s` are provided in VS2019 (also in some earlier versions), which takes a pre allocated pointer in which value need to be returned and hence safe to use.